# everywhere convergent trigonometric series

Tags: power-series, trigonometric-series

Is there an explicit example of a one-sided trigonometric series 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{int}$ converging everywhere but for which the sequence of the coefficients is not in $\ell^2$?

Comment: The coeffients are real numbers? Maybe you refer to the *sequence* of coefficients converging in $l^2$..

Comment: By looking up $l^2$ it seems you may be seeking such an everywhere  convergent trig series for which the sum of the squares of the $a_n$ diverges. Please confirm this in the question, or at least in a comment. Another issue: By saying "one sided" trig series, do you just refer to the index $n$ ranging over non-negative integers, as opposed to over all integers?

Comment: coffeemath your second comment is not correct.  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ converges, but not $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: You're right, will delete my previous comment.